# Java PNG Filter Reconstruction

Tags: java, filter, png

I am trying to reconstruct a PNG image given byte[] that's already un-compressed (inflate). Here's my code for filter reconstruction:

```
private byte[] unfilterBytes(byte[] input) {
        byte[] unfiltered_data = new byte[input.length - mHeight];
        //calculate width based on color type
        int stride = 0;
        int max_bytes_per_pixels = 0;
        switch(mColorType){
            case 0:     //Greyscale - Each pixel is a greyscale sample
                if(mBitDepth <= 8){
                    stride = mWidth;
                }else{
                    stride = mWidth*2;
                }
                max_bytes_per_pixels = 1;
                break;
            case 2:     //Truecolor - Each pixel is an RGB triple
                stride = mWidth*(mBitDepth>>>3)*3;
                max_bytes_per_pixels = 3;
                break;
            case 3:     //Indexed-Color
                stride = mWidth;
                max_bytes_per_pixels = 1;
                break;
            case 4:     //Greyscale with Alpha
                stride = mWidth*(mBitDepth>>>3)*2;
                max_bytes_per_pixels = 2;
                break;
            case 6:     //Truecolor with Alpha
                stride = mWidth*(mBitDepth>>>3)*4;
                max_bytes_per_pixels = 4;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        int i = 0, j, bytes_written = 0;
        byte[] previous_scanline = new byte[stride];
        for(i=0; i<stride; ++i){
            previous_scanline[i] = 0x00;
        }
        i = 0;
        while(i < input.length){
            byte filter_code = input[i++];
            //unfilter
            //if(filter_code != 0) System.err.printf("Filter[%d]: %d\n", i, filter_code);
            switch(filter_code){
                case 0x0:
                    //None
                    System.arraycopy(input, i, unfiltered_data, bytes_written, stride);
                    System.arraycopy(input, i, previous_scanline, 0, stride);
                    i += stride;
                    break;
                case 0x1:
                    //Sub
                    System.arraycopy(input, i, unfiltered_data, bytes_written, max_bytes_per_pixels);
                    System.arraycopy(input, i, previous_scanline, 0, max_bytes_per_pixels);
                    i += max_bytes_per_pixels;
                    for(j=max_bytes_per_pixels; j<stride; ++j, ++i){
                        unfiltered_data[i] = (byte)( (input[i] + unfiltered_data[i-max_bytes_per_pixels]) & 0xff );
                        previous_scanline[j] = unfiltered_data[i];
                    }
                    break;
                case 0x2:
                    //Up
                    for(j=0; j<stride; ++j, ++i){
                        unfiltered_data[i] = (byte)( (input[i] + previous_scanline[j]) & 0xff );
                        previous_scanline[j] = unfiltered_data[i];
                    }
                    break;
                case 0x3:
                    //Average
                    for(j=0; j<max_bytes_per_pixels; ++j, ++i){
                        unfiltered_data[i] = (byte) Math.floor( previous_scanline[j]>>>1 );
                        previous_scanline[j] = unfiltered_data[i];
                    }
                    for(j=max_bytes_per_pixels; j<stride; ++j, ++i){
                        unfiltered_data[i] = (byte) Math.floor( (unfiltered_data[i-max_bytes_per_pixels] + previous_scanline[j])>>>1 );
                        previous_scanline[j] = unfiltered_data[i];
                    }
                    break;
                case 0x4:
                    //Paeth
                    byte a, b, c;
                    for(j=0; j<max_bytes_per_pixels; ++j, ++i){
                        a = 0x0;
                        b = previous_scanline[j];
                        c = 0x0;
                        unfiltered_data[i] = paeth(a, b, c);
                        previous_scanline[j] = unfiltered_data[i];
                    }
                    for(j=max_bytes_per_pixels; j<stride; ++j, ++i){
                        a = unfiltered_data[i-max_bytes_per_pixels];
                        b = previous_scanline[j];
                        c = previous_scanline[j-max_bytes_per_pixels];
                        unfiltered_data[i] = (byte) ( (input[i] + paeth(a, b, c)) & 0xff );
                        previous_scanline[j] = unfiltered_data[i];
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.println("Filter byte code: " + Integer.toHexString(filter_code));
                    break;
            }
            bytes_written += stride;
        }

        return unfiltered_data;
    }
```

Here's my paeth function:

```
private byte paeth(byte a, byte b, byte c){
        short p = (short) (a + b - c);
        short pa = (short) Math.abs(p - a);
        short pb = (short) Math.abs(p - b);
        short pc = (short) Math.abs(p - c);
        short pr;
        if(pa <= pb && pa <= pc){
            pr = a;
        }else if(pb <= pc){
            pr = b;
        }else{
            pr = c;
        }
        return (byte)(pr & 0xff);
    }
```

Here I'm using short since Java is signed. I am not sure if I am interpreting the PNG file specification correctly during my filter reconstruction. Any help is appreciated at pointing out what is wrong with my filter reconstruction logic.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Decoded Image]

It would help if I can get some confirmation on the following logic. Given the sample image is:

128x128 with 8bit True-color + alpha

- Scanline is 128 * 4 bytes = 512 bytes (RRGGBBAA)
- There are total of 128 scanlines and a total of 65536 bytes
- The previous byte of x is simply scanline[i-1] and if i-1 is less than 0, then simply use the value 0
- After each scanline is reconstructed, we store this as the previous scanline for other filtering types to use on the next iteration
- The byte before x on the prior scanline is simply previous_scanline[i-1] and if i-1 is less than 0, then simply use the value 0

Any of the above assumptions are wrong?

Comment: It would help if you pointed out why you *think* your implementation is incorrect.

Comment: Well the image decoded in RRGGBBAA is visually different and since I have verified my inflation to be correct, this is the only place it is incorrect. I can't seem to be sure what the PNG specification mean when filtwr reconstructing.

Comment: I found following the specs **to the letter** very helpful when doing this in C. Can't recall, though, how I managed to weed out bugs. Do you have a set of test images, each using only one of the different filters?

Comment: I know that filter type zero is working as it is the simplest: discard the filtering byte. I can confirm it is working because it can decode Index Color and True Color + Alpha with all filter bytes being zero. How would you find an image with only say filter type 1?

Comment: Check your filter functions. At a glance, it seems you are switching between using `previous` and `unfiltered`. Pick one method. Compare the `removeRowFilters` function in my own [pngdefry C source](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html). Your skewed result shows something fishy in your updating of stride as well -- you might want to fix that first.

Comment: Each switch statement increments i either directly or through the for-loop. Would you say my stride update is still incorrect after this?

Comment: Look at your output -- that is the reason for my statement.

Comment: In case this helps, here's a (my) PNG decoder in plain Java https://code.google.com/p/pngj The code for defiltering is here http://goo.gl/lo0xMl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any of the above assumptions are wrong?

It depends on what you call "scanline". Does it include the filter byte or not?

> There are total of 128 scanlines and a total of 65536 bytes

There are 128 scanlines, each of what has 512 bytes plus one filter byte. Hence the total count of bytes in the IDAT chunks is 128 * 513 = 65664.

> The previous byte of x is simply scanline[i-1] and if i-1 is less than 0, then simply use the value 0

I guess you mean the previous byte in the same row. That's wrong. You need to use `scanline[i-b]` where `b` = bytes per pixel (in your case, b=4). That's explained in the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html)

> The byte before x on the prior scanline is simply previous_scanline[i-1] and if i-1 is less than 0, then simply use the value 0

Same remark as before.

> After each scanline is reconstructed, we store this as the previous scanline for other filtering types to use on the next iteration

That's ok.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try to decode accordingly and see if it works.

Comment: The biggest mistake is that I mis-counted the index of the unfiltered data. For each scanline I processed, I need to shift the index back by 1 to avoid the filter code byte.